# Trigger event after event.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, callback, dom-events

I'm catching clicks on submit button of a form. I do `event.preventDefault()` to disable default browser action so I'm able to do my stuff after clicking to button. I this case I do AJAX call to server. By response from the server I want to choose if continue with form submission or do something else.

```
$inviteSubmitForm.find('input[name="accept"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success  : function(data) {

            if (data.something) {
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Problem with this is, that I'm unable to cast default action of clicked button, cos logic is in AJAX callback. So `return true` just end callback function - I cannot use this simple trick. Also moving `e.preventDefault()` is no-go, cos form gets submitted immediately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trigger to submit the form:

```
$inviteSubmitForm.find('input[name="accept"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success  : function(data) {

            if (data.something) {
                // don't submit
            } else {
                $inviteSubmitForm.submit();
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution is OK and working, but - I have several submit buttons in form. If I want to distinguish buttons by this method, I must append <input type="hidden"> with name of original submit button. This is still OK, but I'm looking form systematic clean solution - recast old event of original button.

Comment: @srigi: Why would you need an hidden input field? You are already doing: `find('input[name="accept"]')` which should only be 1 'type' button. Also if you would have the same function handle multiple buttons just add a simple switch. Would you like me to add an example for you?

Comment: Personally, I'd like to see how to handle this at an event level.

Comment: @PeeHaa - if you submit form by Javasctipt, submit buttons are not sended to the server as in classic "HTML" submit. So if you want to distinguish which button was hit, you must emulate this by including <input type="hidden"> with name of original button. I think, that `$inviteSubmitForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="accept" value="Accept">'); $inviteSubmitForm.submit();` is the simplest sollution.

Comment: @Diodeus: And I would like to see I was rich as hell ;) neh serious. Don't think there is an `.preventPreventDefautlt()`.

Comment: @srigi: or you can append the name of the submit button that was clicked to the url to which you are posting. This would prevent you from adding extra markup in your HTML